# Why is my ComboBox taking so long to drop down when I run my program from within Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, mvvm, combobox

In my view model, I have two related properties.  Their implementations look like this:

```
public string Code
{
   get { return _Code; }
   set
   {
      if (_Code != value)
      {
         _Code = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Code");
         OnPropertyChanged("RelatedCodeList");
      }
}

public List<Code> RelatedCodeList
{
   get
   {
      return CodeLists[Code];
   }
}
```

`CodeLists` is a `Dictionary<string, List<Code>>`.

I have a `ComboBox` that's bound to `RelatedCodeList`; its implementation looks like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding RelatedCode, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedCodeList}">
```

This seems simple enough, and it works, except for one thing.  When I change `Code` in the UI and then click on the combo box, it takes two or three seconds to drop down.  Even if the list has less than 10 items in it.

What could cause this?  It's not collection-change events:  `List` doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, and anyway the collection isn't changing.  It doesn't seem to be happening inside the view model; I've put breakpoints into the property getters, and the getters break as soon as the property-change events are raised; they don't get called when the combo box is dropping down.  It doesn't seem to be the item rendering:  there's no data template defined for the `Code` class, and the implementation of `ToString()` in that class is trivial.

What am I overlooking?

**Edit**

I followed up on Will's suggestion, and found that this doesn't happen unless I'm running under the debugger.  If I just run the executable (even the Debug build), it performs just fine.

So in an effort to make this question actually useful, let's reword it:  Why does this happen?  And, more importantly, if the debugger is to blame, is there any way for me to tell that the debugger is bollixing things up, so that I don't spend hours trying to find the cause of problems that don't actually exist?

Comment: Anything suspicious in the output window? I encountered something like this before and i think it had to do with UI-Automation throwing exceptions for no apparent reason. It would be helpful if you could post some standalone code which reproduces the problem by the way.

Comment: Is there any relevant code in the RelatedCode get or set methods? Have you tried removing the SelectedItem binding?

Comment: How many items in your `RelatedCodeList` collection? Is there any `BindingErrors` in your output window?

Comment: Because the debugger is attached, and at this point VS is loading a bunch of assemblies into memory?  I've been experiencing this *a lot* recently.

Comment: No binding errors.  No exceptions of any kind in the Output window.  I've instrumented all of the setters and getters that are being called in this process, and not one of them is taking as much as 10 milliseconds.  But kudos to Will for the idea that the debugger is to blame:  this doesn't happen outside of VS.

Comment: You are right - it is returning a List.  I deleted my bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

This type of question is really tough to answer because you haven't really given enough information. Nothing that you've supplied could be causing the issue.

But using my amazing powers of deduction, I'm going to suggest that you check that you don't have any circular OnPropertyChanged calls happening - I've noticed that these can stall the debugger but go almost unnoticed otherwise.

Otherwise, check your CodeLists indexer.

Comment: I agree that nothing that I've supplied *should* be causing the issue.  But I can't find anything else.  `CodeLists` is a `Dictionary<string, string>`, so its indexer is (unless something *profoundly weird* is going on) just fine.  I hooked up a listener to the PropertyChanged events and nothing out of the ordinary was happening there either.

Answer (score 0):

I found that WPF ComboBox is lacking of Virutal Stack Panel and it makes rendering slow at UI. Including Virtual Stack Panel is a perfect solution for this.

Include Following into your window / user control resources

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VSP">
    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Update ComboBox XAML -

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataSource}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource VSP}"/>
```